# How to talk about the light which is lit?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-choice, word-request, sentence-structure

I have a ball in the house which when thrown down lights up a light inside it.

The light inside the ball is like a sparkling and blinking blub.

What should I say now?

A. See, light inside the ball is burning.
B. See, light inside the ball is lit.
C. See, light inside the ball is turned on.

Can light is burning be ever used?

Comment: I'd use one of these: *See, the light is on. See, the light is blinking. See, the light is still working.*

Comment: To say that an electric light is *burning* sounds very old-fashioned to this speaker of American English.  "Lit" or "on" sound more fluent.

Answer (score 1):

First, we are talking about a specific light.  So we use the definite article - "the" - to preface "light".

All of the three sentences are acceptable, once "the" is added.

Another option is "See, the light inside the ball is on".

"the light ... is lit" is a little repetitious, so is less recommended. But it is not wrong.

"the light ... is burning" might be less good if the light looks less warm and firey, and more cool and electric.  But it's not wrong.